# Certbot having problems finding my ACME challenge on nodejs web application

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a NodeJS web service which is exposed with a reverse-proxy using Nginx. I am trying to renew an SSL certificate from certbot, and for renewal it looks at `domain.com/.well-known` for the ACME challenge. However, the way I have the node service configured is that the root path does not serve files, the root of the domain is caught and handled by my web service. My actual public webroot is at `domain.com/public`, so the ACME challenge is really at `domain.com/public/.well-known`

So there are two ways to fix this, I could figure out how to tell certbot to look at `domain.com/public/.well-known` instead of `domain.com/.well-known`, or figure out how to somehow "proxy" `domain.com/public/.well-known` to `domain.com/.well-known`.

Here is my config and failed attempt at redirecting it:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    ssl_certificate <path to cert>;
    ssl_certificate_key <path to key>;
    server_name domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location /.well-known {
        return 302 "http://{$host}/public{$request_uri}";
    }
}
```

Comment: What ACME client are you using? Standard certbot? How are you running it?

Comment: @whites11 Just using `certbot renew`, sorry.

Comment: How did you specify the webroot to be used?

Comment: @whites11 The webroot is a folder called "public" in my nodejs app, that is where the certbot webroot for this domain is set to. That folder is served only on the `/public` route. I can't put it on the root path because requests to the root path are caught and handled by the nodejs app and rendered from handlebars templates. I only use the `/public` route for serving static js and css files. It's putting the challenge in the right place, it' just not looking for it in the right place when it does the verification.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot use path based (HTTP) domain validation, you can use DNS based domain validation.

```
certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges dns -d mydomain.com
```

This will prompt you to add a TXT record to your domain's DNS server. Add the record and then wait a few minutes before pressing ENTER to continue.

The copy the new certificates to your desired location.

[Certbot User Guide](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html)

Comment: Worked perfectly, that's exactly what I needed, configure certbot without nginx nor apache on my nodeJS api.